# Show proportionality using Pi theorem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, dimensional-analysis

[image]

For context, $A$ is amplitude, so it probably has units of length. $F_0$ has units of $\text{Force}/\text{Mass}$ and $\omega_0$ has units $\text{1/Time}$, $\lambda$ has units $\text{1/Time}$ and $\omega$ also has units $\text{1/Time}$.

To show proportionality, we would need to get $\Pi = c$ for constant $c$, so we can only have $1$ dimensionless quantity.

But if we have $F_0, \omega_0, \omega, \lambda, A$, 5 quantities, I dont see how thats possible.

Comment: A and $F_0$ are the only quantities among the five which involve length. So if A depends on the other four then the dependence on $F_0$ can only be linear since there is no other way to "cancel" the length dimension in $F_0$.

Comment: @Ian, I'm not quite sure I understand. Yes $A, F_0$ are the only ones with length I agree. But how do we show this using the buckingham pi theorem?

Comment: You may be taking "use the Buckingham Pi theorem" a bit too literally. The point is that since $A$ has units of length, if it depends on those four quantities then it must be *any* particular aggregate of those quantities with dimensions of length, times a general nonlinear function of the dimensionless quantities. (This nonlinear function depends on the aggregate you chose to have dimensions of length and on the dimensionless quantities you chose, of course.)

Comment: @Ian, yes I know we would have something like $\Pi_{1} = f(\Pi_2, ...)$, but I thought proportionality only holds if we had something like $\Pi_{1} = c$ for some constant $c$. Can we have proportionality even if we have a non linear function?

Comment: If the nonlinear function does not depend on that independent variable (as in this case) then yes.